# How to roll two dice so they land on pre-determined numbers?

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I am developing a game in Unity in which you throw two dice which should roll normally, but you have to get a predetermined output based on the user input. Say the user enters 2,5 and presses enter, the dice should fall on the ground and roll in such a way that the first die results in 2 and second die results in 5

To achieve this I have split the rolling logic into two parts. The first part runs until the dice touch the ground, using physics, and the second part when it starts rolling slowly I use `leanTween`.

So when I press enter the code is as shown below:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
{
    transform.position = initialPosition;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(75f, 180f, 270f);
    initialPush = true;
    collidedWithGround = false;
    rollCompleted = false;
    // above conditions repeated so that in play mode when u enter the numbers again and get the things done, the values are reset           
     rigidBodyCube.useGravity = true;
     MagnitudeX = Random.Range(0f, 1000f);
     MagnitudeY = Random.Range(0f, 1000f);
     MagnitudeZ = Random.Range(0f, 1000f);
}
```

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
   if(initialPush)
    {
        rigidBodyCube.AddForce(new Vector3(pushForce, -pushForce,0f));                      
        rigidBodyCube.AddTorque(MagnitudeX, MagnitudeY, MagnitudeZ);           
    }
    if (collidedWithGround && !rollCompleted)
    {
        RollDiceToDesiredNumber();
    }
}
```

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Ground")
    {
        //Debug.Log("Dice collided with Ground..........");            
        initialPush = false;
        collidedWithGround = true;
    }
}


private void RollDiceToDesiredNumber()
{
    int diceNumber = int.Parse(finalResult.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text);
    LeanTween.rotateLocal(gameObject, wantedRotation[diceNumber - 1], timeRoll).setOnComplete(() => rollCompleted = true);
}
```

So to explain the above code, when I press enter I make `initialPush` true. In the fixed update I add a sideward force on the pair of dice so that they fall from some space above onto the ground. The `rigidBodyCube.AddTorque` is so that the dice can rotate as they keep falling.

When it hits the ground, to make sure the forward push is ceased, I make `initialPush = false`. Now I make the `collidedWithGround = true`. From there on lean tween takes control of stuff until it gets the result to a determined value.

The value of the wanted rotations which I have given in the start looks like this:

```
wantedRotation[0] = new Vector3(270f, 0, 0);
wantedRotation[1] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
wantedRotation[2] = new Vector3(0, 0, 270f);
wantedRotation[3] = new Vector3(0, 0, 90f);
wantedRotation[4] = new Vector3(180f, 0f, 0f);
wantedRotation[5] = new Vector3(90f, 0f, 0f);
```

It works fine, but not in a realistic way. That is sometimes when it hits the ground, the pair of dice revolve backwards, where it actually had to revolve forward, which gives an awkward look. I tried using the `rotation.lerp` function but the dice are continuously rotating. I tried to search how to rotate the dice slowly using physics until the desired rotation but I am not getting any proper results. I tried to use Lean tween from the moment it was thrown till it hits the ground, but there is this time variable which makes it hard for me to correct predict when it hits the ground correctly.

How can I get a realistic solution for this problem?

Comment: We had to solve a somewhat similar problem in Starlink when your spaceship slams into an obstacle and goes tumbling: we wanted it to "land" or stabilize right-side-up. [Lead gameplay programmer Michael Wasilewski gave a GDC talk showing the solution we used](https://gdcvault.com/play/1026078/Starship-Physics-and-Controls-that) (around 20 minutes into this video), in case that could be a useful starting point for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a dice toss that results in a specific value?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/171339/39518)

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

One way I could see this work would be to pre-bake some rolling dice animations and based on the inputs, change the initial states of the dices. So either change the textures or put the anmiation on empties, parent your dices to them and change their rotation. For randomness, you could make a buch of them and choose one at random at the beginning.

Another way would be to make a real world ''cheating dice'', where you add a gentle force that pulls the right face up or the opposite face down all the time, so that it has more chances of falling the right way. Although you might endup not getting the result you want and having to tweak the settings for hours.

Comment: These seem to be the same answers shared in response to the [previous version of the question here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/171339/39518), which was linked in the comments.